# change toollbar color and font IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitoolbar, ios9

I have a toolbar on my storyboard and want to change the color and Delea source. With the code below I adciocei I can change the color but the font does not change. What's wrong? My source should be "proximaNova-Bold"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self registerCellNamed:@"DeviceLostHeaderCell"];
    [self registerCellNamed:@"DeviceLostDescriptionCell"];
    [self registerCellNamed:@"DeviceLostPhotoCell"];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:82/255.0 green:157/255.0  blue:230/255.0  alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.0]};

    NSDictionary *attributes2 = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"proximaNova-Regular" size:17.0]};


    [self.rigthToolbarItem setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.leftTollbarItem setTitleTextAttributes:attributes2
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.dataTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

}
```

this is my toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that you are using the key `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and setting it to a font, whereas you should be using `NSFontAttributeName`.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Bold" size:17.0]};
```